# Comparar y fusionar 2 arrays en PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando comparar 2 arrays para ver que valores coincidan y en base a ello fusionarlos en uno nuevo.

Este es el código que tengo de lo que estoy tratando de hacer:

```
$array1=array(
    "0" => array(
        "email" => "user1@gmail.com", 
        "name" => "user1",
        "type" => "team"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "email" => "user2@gmail.com",
        "name" => "user2",
        "type" => "individual"
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "email" => "user3@gmail.com",
        "name" => "user3",
        "type" => "individual"
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "email" => "user4@gmail.com",
        "name" => "user4",
        "type" => "individual"
    )
);

$array2=array(
    "0" => array(
        "email" => "user2@gmail.com",
        "status" => "selected"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "email" => "user3@gmail.com",
        "status" => "selected"
    )
);

$array3=array();
```

Comienzo a comparar

```
foreach($array1 as $val1){
    foreach ($array2 as $val2){
        $status='';
        if($val1['email']==$val2['email']){
            $status=$val2['status'];
        }
      $array3[]=array("email"=>$val1['email'],"name"=>$val1['name'],"type"=>$val1['type'],"status"=>$status);
    }
}
```

Esto lo hice ya que me repetían los valores

```
$arrayFussion = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array3)));
```

Pero al imprimir el resultado me muestra algo así:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => user1@gmail.com
        [name] => user1
        [type] => team
        [status] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => user2@gmail.com
        [name] => user2
        [type] => individual
        [status] => selected
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => user2@gmail.com
        [name] => user2
        [type] => individual
        [status] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [email] => user3@gmail.com
        [name] => user3
        [type] => individual
        [status] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [email] => user3@gmail.com
        [name] => user3
        [type] => individual
        [status] => selected
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [email] => user4@gmail.com
        [name] => user4
        [type] => individual
        [status] => 
    )
```

Cuando esperaría obtener algo así:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => user1@gmail.com
        [name] => user1
        [type] => team
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => user2@gmail.com
        [name] => user2
        [type] => individual
        [status] => selected
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => user3@gmail.com
        [name] => user3
        [type] => individual
        [status] => selected
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [email] => user4@gmail.com
        [name] => user4
        [type] => individual
    )
```

Comment: Has probado 'array_merge_recursive' para tu caso? Parece que te podría solucionar tu caso particular....

Comment: Si lo había intentado, pero no resulto, aun así gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array1=array(
    "0" => array(
        "email" => "user1@gmail.com", 
        "name" => "user1",
        "type" => "team"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "email" => "user2@gmail.com",
        "name" => "user2",
        "type" => "individual"
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "email" => "user3@gmail.com",
        "name" => "user3",
        "type" => "individual"
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "email" => "user4@gmail.com",
        "name" => "user4",
        "type" => "individual"
    )
);

$array2=array(
    "0" => array(
        "email" => "user2@gmail.com",
        "status" => "selected"
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "email" => "user3@gmail.com",
        "status" => "selected"
    )
);
```

Una forma de solucionar seria pasar el `$array1` por referencia y cuando coincida el `email` en ambos arreglos, se agrega el `status`

> Para poder modificar directamente los elementos del array dentro de bucle, se ha de anteponer & a $valor. En este caso el valor será asignado por referencia. https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($array1 as &$val1){  //Paso el array1 como referencia
    foreach ($array2 as $val2){
        if($val1['email']==$val2['email']){
            $val1['status']=$val2['status'];  //Agrego al array1 el status
        }
    }
}
unset($val1); //Se elimina la referencia
print_r($array1);
```

Resultado:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [email] => user1@gmail.com 
        [name] => user1 
        [type] => team ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [email] => user2@gmail.com 
        [name] => user2 
        [type] => individual 
        [status] => selected ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [email] => user3@gmail.com 
        [name] => user3 
        [type] => individual 
        [status] => selected ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [email] => user4@gmail.com 
        [name] => user4 
        [type] => individual )
)
```

Funcionando: https://onlinegdb.com/HkjbgHsdN

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona de maravilla

Answer (score 1):

Una manera sencilla que tienes de hacerlo es creando un nuevo array con las keys de los emails y haciendo un array_merge en el caso de que exista el mismo email.

```
$array3 = [];
foreach(\array_merge($array1, $array2) as $item) {
        $array3[$item['email']] = \array_merge($array3[$item['email']] ?? [], $item);
}
$array3 = \array_values($array3);
```

https://onlinegdb.com/r1mCdUo_4

Comment: Muchas gracias, también funciona bastante bien, gracias

Comment: Comprueba las dos soluciones con gran cantidad de datos y verás la diferencia de rendimiento

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de mucha utilidad tu respuesta